# Inaccessible base in second level descendant class

Tags: c++

Why can't i make a class member of type Grand?

```
class Grand
{};

class Father :private Grand
{};

class Son :public Father
{
    Grand g; //This gives error. Class Grand is Inaccessible.
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixes it:

```
class Grand
{};

class Father :private Grand
{};

typedef Grand MyGrand;

class Son :public Father
{
    MyGrand g; // This now compiles successfully
};
```

The problem is that specifiers like private affect **accessibility** but not **visibility** in name look up. So when you say `Grand g` the compiler first walks up the inheritance tree, in case you end up resolving something like `Grand::MyType`.

Answer (score 4):

because it automatically add the parent class "spacename" before the functions, and Father::Grand::Grand() (constructor) is private

```
class Grand
{};

class Father :private Grand
{};

class Son :public Father
{
    ::Grand g; 
};
```

works because use the class Grand directly, and not the inheritance

Comment: This solution doesn't work if this is all happening in a namespace. If so you'd need to say `TopNS::MiddleNS::Grand` or just `MiddleNS::Grand` (otherwise you'll get a "not found in global namespace") error. My `typedef` solution avoids this problem.

Comment: indeed, but honestly, i don't like the style of your solution (it's a purely esthetic judgment though), and i was more happy with the esthetic of my solution :-P, isn't there a way to call the "actual namespace" ? , without including classes of course

Comment: I agree with you, if you could say `__enclosing_namespace::Grand` I think that would look better. But I don't know of anything like that in standard C++.

Comment: shame :-P that's why i, actually upvoted your post and comment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `Grand` is hidden by `Father` inheriting `private`ly, try using a global scope:

```
class Son : public Father {
    ::Grand g;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why you can't create a **member** of type `Grand`. A class that doesn't inherit from `Grand` at all ought to be able to do that.